# Wxwidgets - How can I add resize event handler to make the "X" drawing to resize with the window?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wxwidgets

I am trying to learn WxWidgets with C++ (I am very new at this), and I have created a window with a black background color and has a big red "X" on it. I have to edit the code so that the "X" changes its size with the window as I am resizing the window. How can I properly implement the resize event handler to this code?

Here's a screenshot of what my code produces: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d52yY.jpg

Here's what I have so far"

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/dcbuffer.h>

class MyCanvas : public wxWindow
{
public:
    MyCanvas(wxWindow* parent)
        : wxWindow(parent, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxFULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)

    {
        SetBackgroundStyle(wxBG_STYLE_PAINT);
        Bind(wxEVT_PAINT, &MyCanvas::OnPaint, this);
    }
private:
    void OnPaint(wxPaintEvent&)
    {
        wxAutoBufferedPaintDC dc(this);

        dc.SetPen(*wxRED_PEN);
        dc.SetBrush(*wxBLACK_BRUSH);

        dc.DrawLine(0,0,485,485);
        dc.DrawLine(0, 485, 485, 0);

    }
 };


class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame()
        : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, _("Resizable X"), wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(500, 525))
    {
        wxBoxSizer* bSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

        bSizer->Add(new MyCanvas(this), 1, wxEXPAND);
        SetSizer(bSizer);
    }

};

/**** MyApp ****/
class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit()
   {
        MyFrame* frame = new MyFrame();
        frame->Show();

        return true;
    }
};


IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)
```

Comment: An example code would be very appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: To begin with, don't hard-code the coordinates in the drawing code. Get the actual size from the window instead.

Comment: I tried that but every time I try to assign GetSize from wxWindow to x1,x2,y1, and y2 to use them in "dc.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2)", the code doesn't draw the X. I only see a black background.I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to implement your resize handler is to do the following in `MyCanvas` ctor:

```cpp
Bind(wxEVT_SIZE, [this](wxSizeEvent& event) { Refresh(); event.Skip(); });
```

This will fully refresh your canvas every time it is resized, i.e. will generate a `wxEVT_PAINT` that will result in a call to your existing `OnPaint()` handler.

Of course, for this to be actually useful, your `OnPaint()` should take the current window size into account, i.e. use `GetClientSize()` instead of hardcoded `485`.